# Two instances of directive in DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two instances of one directive in the DOM.

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

... later in the dom

```
<my-directive</my-directive>
```

The directive uses a controller($scope), and everything works as expected, except when I put this in the directive...

```
...
scope: {},
controller: function( $scope ){
....
```

When I add isolated scope the first directive shows nothing, and the second directive shows up just fine.

The directive calls on a service to fetch data.

Here is a working jsFiddle with my version of angularjs and the issue.

[broken jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CriddleCraddle/rcqrjke5/3/)

**UPDATE #1**
Here is an example of what I want working. For some reason it works in the plunker, but not on my local.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Av0tJccHZEtAjUbClbsC?p=preview)

**UPDATE #2**

Using the above plunker I was able to work through the issue with a colleague.

The issue was with something I had done in my local file, but not in the plunker (which had always worked).

Here is the shortened code

```
app.directive("rsGeneralLinksMenu", [ 'menuService', function( menuService ){

  var shared = {};

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'directives/consumer-portal/menu.html',
    scope: {},

    controller: function( $scope ){

      menuService.getTemplates( menuTemplateCallback );
      shared.$scope = $scope;

    } // end link
  }; // end return

  function menuTemplateCallback( template ){
    shared.$scope.links = template;
  }
}]);
```

What I learned here...

Angularjs runs through the directive and returns the return object (and anything IN the return object.

As you can see I am setting var shared = {}; outside of the return so that I can later attach the $scope controller and use $scope outside of the return statement without having to pass it around in parameters. However, this had a side effect I didn't realize at the time.

When the directive loads, it creates the 'shared' object and attaches $scope to it, which is where I draw the returned server data from calling shared.$scope.links, thus updating the HTML template.

If you recall, I have two instances of this directive in the DOM. When the second instance was created, it was overwriting the first directive's shared.$scope object with directive number two's $scope, thus removing any references for the first directive's $scope.

By removing the 'shared' object and just nesting the callback inside of the directive's controller, the callback referenced the correct $scope object per instance and now everything works as it should.

It is now like this...

```
app.directive("rsGeneralLinksMenu", [ 'menuService', function( menuService ){

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'directives/consumer-portal/menu.html',
    scope: {},

    controller: function( $scope ){

      menuService.getTemplates( menuTemplateCallback );

      function menuTemplateCallback( template ){
        $scope.links = template;
      }
    } // end link
  }; // end return
}]);
```

The above plunker link now has a complete working example. My two directives only need one server data return to use the same data, however I broke it up a bit in the plunker to show how both instances of the directive contain their own scope object.

**Wow, that was fun learning that!!!!**

Comment: what you are trying to do isn't going to work.  Read here: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/

Comment: is there a reason you can't or choose not to give the directive a template? http://jsfiddle.net/2wutLkha/

Comment: I have one in my directive, however I didn't know how to include a large template using jsFiddle, so I just put it in each element in the dom but just a small bit that still causes the issue; should be same thing.

Comment: I don't necessarily need isolated scope, but I do need a way for this directive to notify it's parent directive somehow. I was going to use two-way binding and add a variable in scope: { mydirectiveBroadcast: '=' },

Comment: Claies: just for your own information, Angulasjs can do what I asked without any special coding.

Comment: Dave: post as the answer and I'll vote it.